# My freezer won't go more than 5 degrees below freezing. Thermostat seems OK so what's up?

Tags: electrical, repair, refrigerator, appliances

My Samsung fridge-freezer won't go more than 5 degrees below freezing. The thermostat seems fine and has the correct resistance for its current temperature.

What else could be wrong?

The display on the front shows the freezer at -20C (I'm in the UK) when the actual temp is only -6C which isn't enough for a freezer - it should be at -18C.  The fridge compartment is fine and sits at the correct temperature of 5C above zero within 2 degrees or so.

There is no icing up. The defrost element works well (ouch) and there was no ice anywhere when I took off the cover in the freezer section.

What else should I check before calling out a (horrendously expensive) engineer?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
So I took the thermistor out of the 'housing' and exposed it to free air at the very top of the freezer and no difference at all.  *However*, if I put the thermistor directly in a bowl of hot water, the freezer happily proceeds to move towards the correct temp of 18 degrees below freezing. What gives?!  The thermistor is completely accurate for temps above 0C so could it be it only fails once frozen? Seems very unlikely!  No idea what else could be wrong :(

Comment: The fact that the display shows that temp suggests either the sensor board is badly miscalibrated or there's a small "cold spot" right where the thermistor probe sits. I'm betting the former.

Comment: See edit! I'm so confused...

Comment: It seems I can use software settings to bias the real temp to up to 4.5 degrees below the display temp, but I'd need at least 12 degrees C of movement to make my -6 degree freezer reach -18C (which is regarded as the "normal" temp for freezers)

Comment: I was thinking low Freon but when you heated the thermistor the fridge got colder so it has to be in the controller calibration. When I check thermocouples I do an ice water , boiling water compensation adjustment on the controllers, I would check to see if your board has those, if the span is not set with enough gain it may read the correct temp but not fire the compressor until it gets out of range.

Comment: My 10 yr old Samsung with a freezer drawer in the bottom is -18 C , 0 F. I never checked it until now.

Comment: Needing to recalibrate seems odd... The thermistor is the exact correct resistance at each temperature I've tested it at, so it seems nothing has changed since new. I'm not sure how to recalibrate but I will check the service manual.

Comment: The issue is it is a Samsung . Great phones but terrible appliances. I have had my dealings with their stuff. Ovens that can't maintain temperature or get up to temperature etc..

Comment: Yeah I ended up replacing it with an LG.